# Jquery Uploadify plugin do not find Uploader file

Tags: jquery, asp.net, uploadify

I'm trying to use Uploadify plugin for upload image on my webapplication.
I'm actually using ASP/VB.net.

This is my jquery method for the upload:

```
           $(function() {
                $('#file_upload').uploadify({
                    'preventCaching': false,
                    'swf': 'Scripts/uploadify.swf',
                    'uploader': 'Scripts/Upload.vb',
                    'cancelImg': 'Scripts/uploadify-cancel.png',
                    'buttonText': 'Browse Files',               
                    'folder': 'Uploads',
                    'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
                    'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
                    'multi': true,
                    'auto': true
                });
            });
```

When i try to upload something i get a 404 error on the uploader file "Upload.vb",
but i'm pretty sure that file it's in the right directory "Scripts".
The strange thing is i've not problem with the swf file that it's in the same directory.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

for to upload the file, you need a generic controller (Handler1.ashx), I leave as I have I file:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports System.IO

Public Class Handler1
Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler

Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

    Dim postedFile As HttpPostedFile = context.Request.Files("Filedata")
    Dim savepath As String = ""
    Dim tempPath As String = ""

    tempPath = "Uploads" 'comment: this is the path where the file is uploaded'
    savepath = context.Server.MapPath(tempPath)
    Dim filename As String = postedFile.FileName

    If Not Directory.Exists(savepath) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(savepath)
    End If

    postedFile.SaveAs((savepath & "\") + filename)
    context.Response.Write((tempPath & "/") + filename)
    context.Response.StatusCode = 200
End Sub

ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
        Return False
    End Get
End Property

End Class
```

And the JS File:

```
$(function() {
            $('#file_upload').uploadify({
                'preventCaching': false,
                'swf': 'Scripts/uploadify.swf',
                'uploader': 'Scripts/Handler1.ashx',
                'cancelImg': 'Scripts/uploadify-cancel.png',
                'buttonText': 'Browse Files',               
                'folder': 'Uploads',
                'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
                'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
                'multi': true,
                'auto': true
            });
        });
```

I hope it is helpful, Greetings